# I am walking away, but what should be done?

Tags: discussion, comments, specific-question, etiquette, new-users

I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14197952/561731) with [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14197997/561731) and the following comments ensued:

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/khBkG.png]

### I AM WALKING AWAY

But as this user is *new*, what should be done to explain that this is **not** proper behavior?

Comment: Can I assume those comment flags are yours?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I did not flag **anything** yet. I am waiting till I know what should be done. New users should be handled delicately (I think).

Comment: Well, there's your answer. Even if it's a new user, the fact that he's calling you an ass for trying to answer his question doesn't really help his case. In any case, you trust us, don't you? ;)

Comment: I'd just delete the answer and not bother.

Comment: @Chichiray I am not removing my answer that could be helpful to future visitors ^_^

Comment: Yea, I trust you @BoltClock'saUnicorn ^_^

Comment: It's not a real and localized question. How's that helpful for future visitors?

Comment: @Chichiray the error message.

Comment: You voted to close the question.  That kind of implies that you think, in it's current form, it's not good for the site.  And...you didn't try to improve the question, so it looks like your opinion hasn't changed.

Comment: @jadarnel27 I voted to close as localized. Because that is what it was. But just because it was localized, it does not mean the content is not useful -- it should **not** have been deleted.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA  isn't the definition of "too localized" in the scope of closing questions "unlikely to help future visitors"?

Comment: Ehhhh. There is a fine line @SamIam

Comment: There are thousands, if not tens of thousands of questions with that error message, so I don't think there is any value to keeping the question around. And your answer, while fine, isn't teaching him how to properly catch errors, so its usefulness to future generations is questionable...

Comment: @Pekka and now it has 1 undelete and 1 reopen vote too.. unbelievable

Comment: @Pekka So you're saying it is the *opposite* of too localised.

Comment: @Asad I'm saying "I don't care what it is as long as it's thoroughly burninated" :)

Comment: @Pekka Well, mission accomplished in that case. I think this question can be closed now that the topic of "what to do about inflammatory comments" is off the table.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA: please stop trying to abuse the system to gain more rep. You voted to close, yet you answered. Then you complained. If you think the question should be closed, then don't answer it. Closing and answering is often seen as poor, as it's sending a mixed message. And then [asking for it to be undeleted](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/11?m=7055157#7055157)... After **you** voted for it to be closed? And all it does is abuse the system (just like you constantly linking the post from here). Please stop...

Comment: @ircmaxell, answer and closing is fine and accepted behavior on Stack Overflow.  All questions deserve answers, even if they need to be closed.  It is not abuse.

Comment: @LanceRoberts: that why I said *is often seen as poor, as it's sending a mixed message*. That behavior in itself isn't abuse. It's frowned upon (at least by the PHP sub community), but definitely isn't abuse... But coupled with the rest of the user's recent activity, it is apparent (to me at least) that he *is* trying to abuse the system... And that was my point...

Comment: @卐웃웃웃웃웃웃웃ᗷᙓᗢᖇᓮᘐᓰﬡᗩᒪ웃웃웃웃웃웃웃卐 - are the swastikas really necessary in your username?

Comment: @AdamRackis what the hell...

Comment: @AdamRackis i have to recruite  some more person due to security reason now everything is ok ... so some are gone now .. lol

Comment: @卐웃ᙓᗢᓮᘐᓰﬡ웃卐 I do not see how your username is "funny" at all.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA: A note: He is an Indian, and swastikas were a prominent Hindu symbol waaay before Hitler came along. He's probably not trying to be offensive here. Though I realize that it may rub people the wrong way, and offend new users, so I hope he changes it back..

Comment: @卐웃ᙓᗢᓮᘐᓰﬡ웃卐: Recru— wait, what?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn some extra ... 웃웃웃

Comment: @Manishearth - ahhhhhh.  Thanks for the info.  Interesting aside, I just read a cracked.com article that mentioned that the "heil hitler" salute gesture was an American patriotic gesture well before Hitler came along, too.

Comment: @AdamRackis: Ick. Hitler ruined a lot of things. For example, the Aryan race now has lots of negative connotations attached to it, while it is just a race (again, close ties to India), nothing more. :/

Comment: In addition to already knowing what to do about this situation, you should also be able to write a not-completely-useless question title.

Answer (score 24):

You aren't new here. You know full well what is the Stack Exchange approach for offensive comments.

Flag them, comment constructively, and that's about it.

This exact question was posted **dozens** of times here on meta, I fail to see what made you confused?

Answer (score 10):

To answer your original question, flag any comments that are rude or offensive and stop responding if the discussion degrades into name calling. You should not need to explain basic etiquette to any user, new or otherwise. A moderator will come along to get rid of the comments.

This does not need to be brought up on Meta except in cases where the normal avenues available to you (flagging, ignoring) are insufficient.

Comment: Fine words, +1 from me

Answer (score 2):

I think you did fine trying to explain things to him, some people just don't take constructive criticism well.  Of course, then you walk away and go answer someone's question who cares.